# Creating VLANs or Subnets to simulate corporate environment

Tags: networking, virtualization, vlan, subnet

I am currently using ESXi and a Dell R610 to simulate a 100% vitalized environment. It is going to be setup like a small company. I plan on having a webserver for the company, possibly email server, a extranet, intranet, DMZ, etc. This is going to be setup so I can practice ethical hacking and making my way from a few different options such as establishing foothold through a external web server, simulating being within the network as a employee, etc. My question would be should I be using subnets or VLANs to segment each network off? So like the web server should be able to communicate with everyone, but some private servers in the intranet of the company should not be accessed by the web server. So if someone were to gain access to the web server, they would need to keep pivoting deeper into the network until they get onto a box that has a link to the private servers. So should I be looking at VLANs or subnets for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use both, VLANs and Subnets, if you really want simulate small corporate network. For example:

```
VLAN 1 - Users Network 10.125.0.0/24
VLAN 2 - Printers Network 10.126.0.0/24
VLAN 3 - Servers Network 10.127.0.0/24
VLAN 4 - DMZ 10.120.0.0/24
VLAN 5 - WAN 192.168.88.0/24
And so on.
```

With VLANs you could easily configure VM network interfaces.

Comment: Ah ok. I see how you incorporated both putting the VLANs on different subnets. I like that. It helps keep track of where you are while moving through the network.